# Moving a project tree within SVN repository?

Tags: svn, migration

I have a current SVN repository with multiple projects. In the form:

```
/Project/trunk/code.cs
```

These projects are being split out into their own new repositories on a new server. I've tried using svnadmin with svndumpfilter to dump the individual projects.

We would like to load them into the root of the new repository like:

```
/code.cs
```

but the svnadmin load seems to want to load back into the same structure, and, complains because it does not already exist..

Is it not possible to move these projects to the root of their own repositories and maintain history now that they have lived in this other structure?

EDIT:

I need to clarify. I said I want to maintain history. That really isn't true. I want to permanently move the files, and child directories, to the root as if no past version ever existed there... as if they had all been in the root since day one... while maintaining the file version history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load dump
2. `svn mv` files, remove empty subdir (one additional commit)
3. Use repo or dump repo (HEAD only)|re-create it from this polished dump

Comment: So mv moves history, not from this revision forward.